# Where is the source code of Rake tasks in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

all:

I know how to show all the tasks by typing `rake -T`, and I know how to add my own tasks by add rake files under RAILS_ROOT/lib/tasks. But if I want to view the source code like `rake db:migrate` or `rake doc:app` to see how they work, where can I find those codes?

thank you all :)

eddie

Comment: in case if this helps. In jruby/rails2.3.14 database tasks are found in jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/tasks/databases.rake

Answer (score 32, accepted):

All rails internal rake tasks are in [railties/lib/rails/tasks](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/railties/lib/rails/tasks)

Comment: And likewise for each of the sub-components, like ActiveRecord: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake

Answer (score 3):

All rake tasks of database is in active record.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f47b4236e089b07cb683ee9b7ff8b06111a0ec10/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake